# Omnisharp server does not start with vs-code in a virtual workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I have already posted the question on github [Issue](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/5585), but unfortunately did not receive an answer.

I would like to use Omnisharp with VS-Code to enable intellisense in a [virtual workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/virtual-workspaces) (files are loaded via web requests). However, the Omnisharp server does not start even though I have created the`.csproj` and dependencies as a file. If I download the folder and run it on the local file system then intellisense works.

Is it possible to run OmniSharp with VS-Code in a virtual workspace?